# Java Compiler "Unchecked or unsafe operations" warning with JComboBox

Tags: java, user-interface

Basically I am a rather beginning Java student and I have to create a simple GUI that includes a JComboBox. The window is supposed to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXEMI.jpg

When I compile the code (shown below) it does compile but I get the following warning in jGRASP:

```
Note: Lab6.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

This is my code. I know it means I have to specify something involving data types (right?) but I thought I had specified enough. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lab6 extends JFrame
{
    private String[] choices = {"Hello", "Good-Bye"};

    public Lab6()
    {
        super("218 Lab 6");
        setSize(450,200);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
            panelNorth.add(new JLabel("Welcome Class 218!"));

            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(choices);
            panelNorth.add(comboBox);

            add(panelNorth,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Lab6();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Java 7, [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) requires generics to describe the data which it holds:

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(choices);
```

Not specifying these will produce the compiler warnings shown.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code and pasted it straight into a text file, then compiled it with the standard javac compiler and I didn't get the warning. But when I ran it nothing showed up in the window either.

What version of Java are you using? If its Java 7 try using generics with the combo box. Just like you would with an ArrayList,

```
 JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(choices);
```

I believe that's the correct way to do it as of Java 7, if not I'm positive someone will correct me. And just for the record that warning doesn't mean your program wont run, its a compiler warning not an error and you should still be able to run the program.

Comment: I am on the latest version of Java and I actually figured out the problem behind nothing displaying in the window, the setVisible(true) part has to come at the very end of the constructor.
Also, you were right, I just had to specify the generics with the creation of the JComboBox. Thanks for your input.